# E2K7: Forward email from mailbox (without AD user) to external email address and internal mailbox

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008, forwarding

I should create a new mailbox e.g. test@internaldomain.com. Mails to test@internaldomain.com should be forwarded to test@externaldomain.com and max.mustermann@internaldomain.com. How can I do this with Exchange Server 2007? The best would be without separate Active Directory user, but I'm afraid this is not possible.

I know how I can forward an existing mailbox to an email contact(external) or other internal mailbox. I also know how to forward from test@internaldomain.com to test@externaldomain.com with the help of a email contact. But how to forward to an internal and external email address without an AD user?

Or another way: I can add the test@internaldomain.com to max.mustermann@internaldomain.com. So max.mustermann@internaldomain.com would receive the email. But how can I forward emails from test@internaldomain.com to test@externaldomain.com?

**Solution:**

1. Create a mailbox with test@internaldomain.com.
2. Create an e-mail contact (test@externaldomain.com)
3. Create a distribution group with two members: My external e-mail contact (test@externaldomain.com) and my AD user (max.mustermann@internaldomain.com).
4. Forward test@internaldomain.com to the group.

But now I have created an extra mailbox with AD user, which I wanted to avoid. Also I have now a group with a separate SMTP address, which I also don't need. And I don't know if the difference between Exchange and Active Directory is good (external contact, group not in AD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need to create a Distribution Group, add test@externaldomain.com and max.mustermann@internaldomain.com to this group, and configure forwarding on test@internaldomain.com to forward to this group.

Comment: I created an email contact in E2K7. I also created a distribution group in E2K7 (in AD he didn't find any contact). I have an email contact with test@internaldomain.com. But how to forward this email contact to the group? Now I have two contacts (the internal and the external email), but there is no option to forward the mails ..

Comment: I'm not following. Why do you have an internal Contact (is that even possible?). You need to create a Distribution Group as I described and add test@externaldomain.com and max.mustermann@internaldomain.com to this group. Then configure the forwarding options on the test@internaldomain.com mailbox to forward to this group.

Comment: My solution looks currently like the following: I have created a mailbox with test@internaldomain.com. I also created a distribution group with two members: My e-mail contact (test@externaldomain.com) and my AD user / mailbox (max.mustermann@internaldomain.com). Now I forward test@internaldomain.com to the group. But now I have created an extra mailbox with AD user, which I wanted to avoid. Also I have now a group with a separate SMTP address, which I also don't need. But hey, it's working!

Comment: OK I can't currently find the user nor the distribution group in the AD. When does the changes are visible in the AD?

Comment: If this is a default install of SBS 2008 then in ADUC look in the MyBusiness OU and expand it to find your users, group, and contacts.

Comment: I expanded it but I only find the e-mail contact... I thought the data from the Exchange will be also in the Active Directory, but I made something wrong I think. Nevertheless, the forwarding works (but I created a new mailbox).